# how to assign a value based on condition in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to assign 1 in the response column of the "data1" by matching the altitude column of data2 with its closest altitude value within the corresponding ID1 and ID2.

here I chose the sample of a large dataset as for demo.

data1:

```
structure(list(ID1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), ID2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), altitude = c(0L, 
500L, 1000L, 1500L, 2000L, 0L, 500L, 1000L, 1500L, 2000L, 0L, 
500L, 1000L, 1500L, 2000L, 0L, 500L, 1000L, 1500L, 2000L), response = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

data2

```
structure(list(ID1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2), ID2 = c(1L, 2L, 7L, 9L), 
    altitude = c(500L, 1920L, 128L, 261L), response = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

expected outcome:

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a minimal example.  Please give us smaller input datasets and, even more importantly, the output you expect (or ewant) given those input datasets.  Also, please explain your terminology. For example, what is an "altitudinal bin"?

Comment: thanks, Limey! I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct approach using base R is:

```
to_replace = sapply(1:nrow(data2),function(i){
#get row index
row_idx = with(data1,which(ID1 == data2$ID1[i] & ID2== data2$ID2[i]))
#find the difference
delta = abs(data2$altitude[i] - data1$altitude[row_idx])
row_idx[which.min(delta)]
})

data1$response[to_replace] = 1

   ID1 ID2 altitude response
1    1   1        0        0
2    1   1      500        1
3    1   1     1000        0
4    1   1     1500        0
5    1   1     2000        0
6    1   2        0        0
7    1   2      500        0
8    1   2     1000        0
9    1   2     1500        0
10   1   2     2000        1
11   2   7        0        1
12   2   7      500        0
13   2   7     1000        0
14   2   7     1500        0
15   2   7     2000        0
16   2   9        0        0
17   2   9      500        1
18   2   9     1000        0
19   2   9     1500        0
20   2   9     2000        0
```

If you want to use dplyr, try something like this, where you rbind the two frames, then calculate the absolute difference to the second data.frame within the groups, replace the closest with 1s, and lastly throw out the original dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

rbind(cbind(data1,data=1),cbind(data2,data=2)) %>% 
group_by(ID1,ID2) %>% 
mutate(delta = abs(altitude-altitude[response==1])) %>%
mutate(response=replace(response,delta==sort(delta)[2],1)) %>% 
filter(data==1) %>%
select(-delta)

    # A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   ID1, ID2 [4]
     ID1   ID2 altitude response
   <dbl> <int>    <int>    <dbl>
 1     1     1        0        0
 2     1     1      500        1
 3     1     1     1000        0
 4     1     1     1500        0
 5     1     1     2000        0
 6     1     2        0        0
 7     1     2      500        0
 8     1     2     1000        0
 9     1     2     1500        0
10     1     2     2000        1
11     2     7        0        1
12     2     7      500        0
13     2     7     1000        0
14     2     7     1500        0
15     2     7     2000        0
16     2     9        0        0
17     2     9      500        1
18     2     9     1000        0
19     2     9     1500        0
20     2     9     2000        0
```

Comment: thanks, StupidWolf! it works, but do you know an easier way of other than dplyr?

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it ignores the few identical cases by choosing 2nd closest value. how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Hi @Batbar, yes should be possible, let me quickly try. And there is an easier way, i saw that you had a dplyr tag, so i did dplyr